# combining 2 select query in 1 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to figure out 1 query for a long time. I am new to mysql and query statements. 
I have below 2 queries which I would like to pass into 1 statement so that i can get the desired output.

part 1

```
select custid, fname from customertbl where createdate < 01-01-2011
```

part 2

```
select custid, orddate from ordertbl where orddate < 01-01-2011
```

in general, what i need is the 1st query gives me the list of customer who are created before 01-01-2011.

and 2nd query gives list of who has not made any order after 01-01-2011 .

my desired output is list of customer whose createdate is before 01-01-2011 and have not made any order after 01-01-2011.

I would really appreciate if you could help me out on this.

forgot to mention that custid is same in both tables.

thanks.

--EDIT : to make a little more clear, many customers whose createdate is before 1-1-2011 are still active and i just want the list of customer who are inactive after 01-01-2011

Comment: Can you give us example data on sqlfriddle? that way way we can help better and better understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT usr.custid, usr.fname
    FROM customertbl usr
    WHERE usr.createdate < '01-01-2011' 
    AND NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from orderdate where custid = usr.custid and orddate > '01-01-2011' )
```

I just read your edit and it seems you want to know customers that were created prior to 01-01-2011 and haven't placed any order after that date.  This simplifies things and doesn't require a join unless you need to see their last order date

Comment: NOT EXISTS is very slow on large tables..this should be a LEFT with a WHERE ... iS NULL

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT usr.custid, usr.fname, od.orddate
    FROM customertbl usr
    JOIN ordertbl od ON od.custid = usr.custid
    WHERE usr.createdate < '01-01-2011' AND od.orddate < '01-01-2011'
```

Comment: it still gives me few customer who have orddate after 01-01-2011. i mean those transactions are not listed but the customers are in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.custid, c.fname FROM customertbl c 
LEFT JOIN ordertbl o ONc.custid=o.custid 
WHERE createdate < 01-01-2011 AND orddate < 01-01-2011
```

EDIT:
For customers who do not have orders further than that date:

```
 SELECT c.custid, c.fname FROM customertbl c 
WHERE createdate < 01-01-2011 
AND (SELECT Count(*) FROM ordertbl WHERE custid=c.custid AND orddate>01-01-2011)=0
```

Comment: I tried the your query but the problem with this is that it gives me the customer list who has orderd after the 01-01-2011. I mean that ordertable has multiple orderdate so some of the dates whose orders are less than 01-01-2011 are still counted.

Comment: I hope it made sense to you. pls lemme know if not. and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`

```
SELECT c.custid, c.fname, o.orddate from customertbl c
JOIN ordtbl o ON c.custid = o.custid
WHERE c.orddate < '01-01-2011' AND c.createdate < '01-01-2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select custid, fname 
from customertbl 
where createdate < 01-01-2011 and custid not in (
         select custid
         from ordertbl 
         where orddate > 01-01-2011
     )
```

Or you can use this which is better in performance:

```
select custid, fname 
from customertbl 
where createdate < 01-01-2011 and not exist (
         select custid
         from ordertbl 
         where orddate > 01-01-2011
         And customertbl.custid=ordertbl.custid
     )
```

Comment: using the not exists select 1 with a join is going to be better than a not in clause for preformance

Comment: I inserted that into my answer. But I'm not sure if I got your mean well. I did it right?

Comment: NOT IN and NOT EXIST are very slow on large tables. this should be a LEFT with a WHERE ... iS NULL

Comment: @saeed you can see my answer below. Raymond makes a point as well. Raymond can you share the whole query?